# Java Lambda Multiple operations on a single stream

Tags: java, lambda

**Scenario:** I have a object with 2 functions -->

```
<Integer> getA(); <Integer> getB();
```

I have a list of objects, say `List<MyObject> myObject`.

**Objective** Iterate over the List and get separate sums of A and B's in the List of object.

**My Solution**

`myObject.stream().map(a -> a.getA()).collect(Collectors.summingDouble());`

```
myObject.stream().map(a -> a.getB()).collect(Collectors.summingDouble());
```

**The Question:** How can I do both of these at the same time? This way I will not have to iterate twice over the original list.

@Edit: I was doing this because some of the filters that I used were of O(n^3). Kind of really bad to do those twice.

Benchmark : It really matters if it is T or 2T when the program runs for half hour on an i5. This was on much lesser data and if I run on a cluster, my data would be larger too.

It does matter if you can do these in one line!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write another class to store the total values like this:

```
public class Total {
    private int totalA = 0;
    private int totalB = 0;

    public void addA(int a) {
        totalA += a;
    }

    public void addB(int b) {
        totalB += b;
    }

    public int getTotalA() {
        return totalA;
    }

    public int getTotalB() {
        return totalB;
    }
}
```

And then collect the values using

```
Total total = objects.stream()
        .map(o -> (A) o)
        .collect(Total::new,
                (t, a) -> {
                    t.addA(a.getA());
                    t.addB(a.getB());
                },
                (t1, t2) -> { });
//check total.getTotalA() and total.getTotalB()
```

You can also use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, Integer>` to replace `Total` to avoid writing a new class, but it's still kind of weird because A/B are not in a key-value relationship.

Comment: So essentially you created another Collector? I could just extend my existing class MyObject to collect this by exposing addA/B() to it. Seems like a good way.

Comment: @user6184793 Of course you can use an existing class to replace my `Total` class.

Comment: +1. Note that it's a good idea to benchmark afterward to see if this approach *actually* performs better than iterating once for A and once for B.

Comment: @ruakh, This example is simple. Suppose I had a few filters in place. Something like `.stream()..filter(myObj.x())....filter(myObj.y()).collect....).`

That would definitely mean doing things twice.

Comment: @user6184793: And even so, it's worth benchmarking to see how much of a difference it really makes. You don't want to complicate your code for no benefit.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running Java >= 12, this isn't hard at all to do in a way that's even compatible with parallel streams (unlike the other answers so far), using [Collectors.teeing()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#teeing(java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.stream.Collector,java.util.function.BiFunction)) and [Collectors.summingInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)):

```
int[] totals = myObject.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.teeing(
      Collectors.summingInt(MyObject::getA),
      Collectors.summingInt(MyObject::getB),
      (a, b) -> new int[] {a, b});

int sumA = totals[0];
int sumB = totals[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

The most optimal probably still would be a for loop. Though the stream alternative has parallelism as option, and is likely to become as efficient soon.
Combining two loops to one is not necessarily faster.

One improvement would be to use `int` instead of `Integer`.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("tom","terry","john","kevin","steve");
int n = list.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(String::length));
int h = list.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(String::hashCode));
```

**I favour this solution.**

If one would make one loop, there are two alternatives:

- putting both ints in their own class. You might abuse java.awt.Point class with int x and int y.
- putting both ints in a long. When no overflow, then one can even sum in the loop on the long.

The latter:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("tom","terry","john","kevin","steve");
long nh = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.summingLong((s) -> (s.hashCode() << 32) | s.length()));
    int n = (int) nh;
    int h = (int) (nh >> 32L);
```

Comment: Combining two loops is not significantly faster, but if you are doing things like filter(), it will be definitely bad because of doing all the checks twice!